# The solution of Allen-Cahn equation?

Tags: mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics

$$\frac{\partial\phi(\mathbf{x},t)}{\partial t}=\varepsilon^{2}\Delta\phi-F^{'}(\phi),\ \ \ \mathbf{x}\in \Omega,t>0$$
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial\mathbf{n}}=0\ \ \text{on} \ \partial\Omega$$
$$\phi(\mathbf{x},0)=\phi_{0}(\mathbf{x}),\ \ \mathbf{x}\in \Omega$$

where $F(\phi)=0.25(\phi^2-1)^2$. In some literature, a conclusion says: after certain amount of time, three regions emerge: two phase regions where $\phi ≈ 1$ and −1, respectively, and an interfacial region which is very thin and connects the phase regions. Why? How to explain this interesting conclusion?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, this is just the diffusion equation in one variable? You have $\phi _{xx}$ implying it's only in one dimension. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, there are some written errors in the former description, I have corrected it now.

Comment: Suppose you start with a "nice" initial condition. Then $\varepsilon^2 \Delta \phi$ should be small for a while. Then the $-F'(\phi)$ term will be in control. This term wants to send points where $\phi<0$ closer to $-1$ and to send points where $\phi>0$ closer to $+1$. (If you don't understand, try numerically solving $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=-F'(\phi)$. There are no spatial derivatives here, so there is no difficulty.)

Comment: Eventually, trying to do this will create large curvature in between the adjacent regions. Then the Laplacian term smooths out this curvature. This effect "kicks in" when the interval of transition is of order $\varepsilon$; until then, $\varepsilon^2 \Delta \phi$ is still small. What I've described here is basically the entire point of the Allen-Cahn equation. So you can see more physical intuition by looking up a derivation. I'm not sure how one would rigorously prove what I've said here.

Comment: Can you give me an email? I want to email you to ask some questions about Allen-Cahn equation, Thank you!